# WSL Find my user folder in Windows from Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, case-sensitive

Say that my username in Windows is "John" (`C:\Users\John"`)
My username in WSL Ubuntu is then probably "john" (`/home/john`). I say probably as I think WSL lets you pick a name, but I will always pick the same name as my Windows account so this is not an issue for me.

I want to programmatically find the Windows folder from inside WSL. So I know that the Users folder in Windows is at `/mnt/c/Users` and I know that my WSL name is `john`, but I don't know if the Windows name is `john` or `John` or `JOHN` etc. Linux is rigid in case-sensitivity (this is one area that I think that Microsoft made a brilliant decision for the future - being ultra rigid about case-sensitivity will remain a hassle for decades to come) so I cannot just say `/mnt/c/users/john` as that will fail if the name is not *exactly* `john` with that case-sensitivity.

Is there a way that I could look for `/mnt/c/users/john` and instruct Linux to just find any path that matches anything like that, *no matter the case used* ? The brilliant part of the Windows / PowerShell way is that you are case-insensitive by default and can still just turn sensitivity on whenever you need that. I get why they did it in the early days, but I've never *ever* seen a situation where allowing directories like `stuff`, `Stuff`, `STUFF`, `stUff` all to be able to co-exist in the same location as distinct objects has even been of value (in the real world - rigid case-sensitivity is well past its sell by date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
find /mnt/c/Users -maxdepth 1 -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex '/mnt/c/Users/([Jj][Oo][Hh][nN])'
```

Use find and a regular expression that searches for combination of upper or lower case combinations.

This can alternatively be done with -iregex which represents a case insensitive regular expression search:

```
find /mnt/c/Users -maxdepth 1 -type d -regextype posix-extended -iregex '/mnt/c/Users/john'
```

Comment: If you use `-iregex` instead, search is automatically case insensitive. Of course this would mean that if we have a directory `c/users` or `c/USERS`, this would also be searched.

Comment: Amazing, thanks both, really like the -iregex solution, works nicely. Note: It is technically *impossible* to have `/mnt/c/users` and `/mnt/c/USERS`. Windows is smart enough to *completely ban* such madness so this is impossible in Windows (thankfully! If only Linux did the same...).